# How to unlock Running Shoes and Essence of Defense scroll?

Tags: resident-evil-7

By finishing the game under 4 hours, I unlocked

> a circular saw and x-ray glasses

My next run was for "less than 3 medkits used" and "storage used less than 3 times" achievements (both successful), but this achievements didn't unlocked anything. Still, I know, that

> Running Shoes and Essence of Defense Scroll

can be unlocked somehow. I still didn't complete all the coins, all files, and all Mr. Everywhere's achievements, but I'm not sure which of them may unlock things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL:DR** These items *may* be earned by:

- The Running Shoes may possibly be unlocked by beating the game in under 4 hours, or by only opening the item crate 3 times and finishing the game, or by destroying all 20 Mr. Everywhere bobble heads.
- The Essence of Defense Scroll is unlocked by destroying all 20 Mr. Everywhere bobble heads.

For your particular scenario (since you beat the game by only opening storage 3 times/under 4 hours already, and did not get all the Mr. Everywhere's), I would destroy all the Mr. Everywhere's.  A guide can be found [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-01-27-resident-evil-7-mr-everywhere-statue-locations-mr-nowhere-4298) if you wish to use one.

---

It appears that the Running Shoes *may* be unlocked by beating the game under a certain amount of time.  Basically, as fast as you can muster.

This site said that on Easy-Mode and on their second play through, they beat it in under 4 hours and got the shoes:

> The Running Shoes up your movement speed significantly. We unlocked these on our second play-through. This was an easy-mode run where we finished the game in under 4 hours for a trophy.

**However,** the last link also states that the shoes can be earned by breaking all the bobble heads as well.  This is making players suspect that the rewards at the end can be random.  [Another site](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/25618-all-ending-unlockables-and-how-unlock-them-resident-evil-7.html) claims that the shoes are earned by opening the item crate only 3 times and finishing the game, and that the circular saw it earned by beating the game in under four hours:

> You need to finish the game by opening the item crate only 3 times

There is a [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/residentevil/comments/5q4w7e/re7_unlockables_thread/) regarding the unlocks, and for the running shoes, they state that breaking all the bobble heads gets you them:

> Can someone please confirm what you get for collecting all of the Mr everywhere statues? Thanks
>
> Running Shoes.

The same thread also says that by destroying all the bobble heads, they got the Essence of Defense Scroll:

> And The Essence of Defense, which I got when I finished the game with all 20 Mr Everywhere's.

[Another site claims the same thing for the scroll](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/resident-evil-7-how-to-unlock-all-the-post-game-rewards):

> Speaking of the Mr. Everywhere bobbleheads, they're also tied to another unlockable. You need to have all 20 destroyed to unlock the Essence of Defense

To summarize, it appears that people are up in the air on how to specifically unlock this.  Personally, I would destroy all 20 of the bobble heads and see if you unlock both since you have already done the other things the have been suggested across various websites.  That way, you get two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

I got running shoes and essence of defense after smashing all of the Mr. Everywheres, despite failing to finish the game under 4 hours.

Comment: This really feels like a comment rather than an answer, as it doesn't so much tell *how* to unlock the running shoes or essence of defense as much as it rules out one of the previously stated requirements.